# How to use adduser command with a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find the way to use adduser this way:

```
adduser $username $password
```

or something like this too:

```
adduser -u $username -p $password
```

I know I could use useradd and so, but right now I want to use adduser.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try either?

Comment: Do you see any error message? Are you the root user or using sudo?

Comment: I'm using sudo, yes. adduser returns that $username does not exist.

Comment: *`useradd`* expects the hashed password if any at all. If you want to generate that inline you can use either perl or ssl to salt it for you. To do so securely youll need to handle ***at least*** shell command history, tty snooping, and the current system process list. Probably there are other things. This is not a bad question to ask, necessarily, and you shouldnt have been downvoted without comment, but your question should definitely include something like: "Can i do this *securely?* "

Comment: I dont even know what *`adduser`* is though.

Comment: @mikeserv, `adduser` is basically a wrapper script for `useradd` which will create the user's home directory among other things.

Comment: @mikeserv, pre hashing the password and then using `useradd` in the script is probably the most secure method.

Comment: @Graeme Agreed.

Comment: @mikeserv, although the man page for `adduser` states (for the `-p` option) - `Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.`

Comment: We should probably go to chat on this i guess, but doesnt useradd create home directories?

Comment: @mikeserv not as far as I can tell. `useradd` is specific to Debian based systems AFIAK and does a few things (Debian?) `useradd` can't (or at least is smoother in doing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to specify the password to `adduser` on the command line. The only way to script it is to supply the password (and confirmation) to `stdin`, just as happens when the program interacts with the user. Here is an example using a *here document*:

```
adduser "$username" <<EOF
$password
$password
EOF
```

Also note that if the password could be supplied as an argument, this would be the most insecure way to do it. While the command is running, the arguments can be read by all users. At least this way if the script is only readable by root, then the password won't be readable by everyone.

#### Update

Actually here documents can create temporary files, which would contain the password. The most secure approach seems to be to use `echo` and a pipe (and to ensure `700` permissions for the script):

```
echo "$password
$password" | adduser "$username"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! Could you explain me what exactly <<EOF does? It's for adding that to my script.
------  
I noticed your edit now, I'm going to try that right now.

Comment: @user47579 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Comment: @Graeme More secure still would be to pre salt the password with perl or openssl in a command substituion subshell configured to dump history to /dev/null then feed it into useradd on the command line - you can specify the password on the command line but useradd expects only the hashed version - you could even use your sh -c '' argv0 trick to handle ps output

Comment: @mikeserv, but then the password still has to be passed from the script into `perl` or `openssl` either via a stdin or as an argument. Ultimately you are only adding complexity, but not solving the base problem of how to securely pass the password for a shell script to another program.

Comment: @Graeme No, not via stdin with sh -c 'perl salt' argv0.

Comment: @Graeme I agree its tricky, and maybe not possible, but im curious for sure. You could even handle the heredoc temp file problem with printf \b

Comment: @mikeserv, so how does perl get the password? Surely it must be somewhere in the `sh` command line in which case it is in plain via under the proc directory for the `sh` process.

Comment: This is a good point. Is there any way to get a salt without a new process? Or maybe some nasty eval trick with var values? Possibly invoking either perl or openssl to wait for input then passing it in later on a heredoc file descriptor configured to printf \b the current line...

Comment: Anyway, its a lot of work for possibly little gain -certainly none for me, but i just get curious about this stuff.

Comment: @mikeserv, yeah me too. Though this is more the kind of thing that would be suited to http://security.stackexchange.com. The advice generally is not to do this kind of thing at all if you can avoid it. The above does mitigate to some extent though. The OP seems to be a personal user and not bothered anyway.

Comment: I noticed. Not fair that the question was downvoted without so much as a comment as to why. Cest la vie. Ive got legoland today with little Michael - should probably put the less important out of my head.

Comment: @mikeserv, enjoy.

Comment: One last though - if its debian then youve got dash - no heredoc temp file - dash does heredocs with anonymous pipes. That way you could get your salt with the new perl process in dash -c 'perl salt' i think and a <<heredoc\n${password=abc123} (since thats probably what it is anyway) | useradd $username $(cat) ... Or something. I hope you get my drift - in a rush